# is it wrong to say "to clean your pee" when you want to mean "to remove it"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> **[clean](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/clean_2)** [transitive, intransitive] clean (something) to make something free from dirt or dust by washing or rubbing it
>
> to clean the windows/bath/floor
>
> to clean a wound
>
> Have you cleaned your teeth?
>
> The villa is cleaned twice a week.
>
> I spent all day cooking and cleaning.

---

Ok, your little toddler peed on the chair and his pee is all over the place. Is it wrong to say "**Now, I have to clean your pee**"?

Or "**Now I have to clean the chair**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is wrong to say just “clean” in that context. To give the additional sense of removal you want, you need to use the phrase verb “clean up”.

For example:

Little Oscar pulled handfuls of soil out of the potted plant onto the floor. I used a dustpan and brush to clean up the soil. [*I **cleaned** the floor, but I **cleaned up** the soil.*]

Comment: I made a minor edit to your example. A "pot plant" would be a cannabis plant. A plant in a pot is more often called a *potted plant*.

Comment: @ThePhoton  Hahaha - not in my idiolect! The edit is really no problem but here we call it a “pot plant” (with “potted plant” understood but sounding a little prim) and the ambiguity never arises really. The ambiguity you are sensitive to here reminds me our our Australian concern about AmE “Drug store”. 
Reference: https://www.abc.net.au/gardening/factsheets/pot-plant-health-check/11209256

Comment: Well if your Aunt Nellie has pot plants all around her house you might not have as much need for a drug store.

Answer (score 1):

We normally [clean windows](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22clean%20windows%22&sxsrf=ACYBGNQcCtHxl2h7EtQytzuy1rq3UoVvWQ:1578909676825&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzrK3zqIDnAhXqAGMBHes6Dj0Q_AUoAXoECBkQCQ&biw=1303&bih=647https://), [clean the car](https://books.google.it/books?id=nqQKBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA93&dq=%22clean%20the%20car%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijxIWTqYDnAhXIb5oKHZ-pAj0Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22clean%20the%20car%22&f=false), [clean the floor](https://books.google.it/books?id=A1VkUJ06q2UC&pg=PA37&dq=%22clean%20the%20floor%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwl6OvqYDnAhWj5KYKHZVGBscQ6AEIezAL#v=onepage&q=%22clean%20the%20floor%22&f=false) etc. which means freeing from dirt and dust something that is dirty.  So, telling a child to clean their pee, which is a grammatical sentence,  is literally asking them to wash their pee.

Orbital Aussie's [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/234965/1694) is therefore correct but I'd prefer to say “clean up the floor” or “**mop that up**” (mop up the pee).

> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/synonym/mop_something_up)
>   1. ‘I mopped up the spilt coffee’

and

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/mop-up)
>   1. PHRASAL VERB
>   If you mop up a liquid, you clean it with a cloth so that the liquid is absorbed.
>
> - A waiter mopped up the mess as best he could.
> - When the washing machine spurts out water at least we can mop it up.